# GNUPLOT cbrange setting

Tags: image, matrix, conditional-statements, gnuplot, palette

I am using gnuplot to plot a matrix with the following commands:

```
ub = 1
lb = -ub
set cbrange [lb:ub]
set palette defined (lb "red", 0 "white", ub "blue)
plot 'mydata.dat' matrix ind 19 with image
```

This gives me a matrix which looks great. But I also want a figure that contains only the points with value in domain (0.8:1) and (-1:-0.8).
I think I probability can change the cbrange or change the palette definition. But I have no idea how.
Can anyone show me how to do it (either way)?
Thanks.

Comment: What should happen with the out-of-range points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the numerical value given to `set palette defined` do *not* define absolute values, but are used only for the gradient computation and are mapped to `[0, 1]`. That means that e.g.

```
set palette defined (-1 "red", 0 "white", 1 "blue")
```

and

```
set palette defined (100 "red", 200 "white", 300 "blue")
```

are completely equivalent. The range choosen with `set cbrange` is then mapped to this unity interval.

So, to show only the range `[0.8:1]`, all in the same blue-shaded like in the complete plot, you can check and limit the value of the third, the color column:

```
set palette defined (-1 "red", 0 "white", 1 "blue)
ub = 1
lb = -ub
set cbrange [lb:ub]
plot 'mydata.dat' matrix using 1:2:($3 >= 0.8*ub ? $3 : 0) ind 19 with image
```

This would set all values lower than `0.8*ub` to `0`, and show only the values above `0.8*up` in blue.

If you would set the color range to `[0.8:1]`, the values `0.8` would be shown in red, and `1` in blue.

Accordingly, to show only the range `[-1:-0.8]`, use

```
plot 'mydata.dat' matrix using 1:2:($3 <= 0.8*lb ? $3 : 0) ind 19 with image
```

Comment: works great! Thanks for the details for the set palette and for telling me the hidden indexes for matrix plotting.

Comment: This is how I did: plot 'mydata.dat' matrix using1:2:(($3 > cutoff || $3 < -cutoff) ? $3: 0) ind 19 with image